# Is it possible to use a foreach to make new objects inside an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, xunit

Using XUnit, I want to pass a list of strings to a test (using `ClassData` or `MemberData`). Is there a way to do something like this but with a list:

Before:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetPersonFromDataGenerator()
{
    yield return new object[]
    {
        new Person {"Tribbiani"},
        new Person {"Gotti"},
        new Person {"Sopranos"},
        new Person {"Corleone"}
    };
}
```

After:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetPersonFromDataGenerator()
{
    var listOfPersons = GetList();

    yield return new object[]
    {
        foreach(var p in listOfPersons)
        {
             new Person {p}
        } 
    };
}
```

It needs to be `IEnumerable<object[]>` as that is required by the XUnit `ClassData` and `MemberData` fixtures.

Comment: how did this question get a downvote?

Comment: @EZI I'm guessing that was a joke but I was genuinely asking why someone would downvote this question. Didn't deserve a downvote IMHO

Comment: I am wonder why the down vote as well, I did a lot of research and tried to ask a clear question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonFromDataGenerator()
{
    foreach (var p in GetList())
        yield return p;
}
```

Remember that an enumerator can "yield return" multiple times in a method!

Or if you do really want to return multiple arrays of objects, your code could look something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetPersonFromDataGenerator()
{
    var listOfPersons = GetList();
    yield return listOfPersons.ToArray();
}
```

ToArray() would convert the list into an array for you.

Comment: The `IEnumerable<object[]>` signature is used by xunit for loading parameters for theories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

```
yield return listOfPersons.Select(p=> new Person(p)).ToArray();
```